# Trying to load data from mysql into jsgrid

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, jsgrid

I have just started learning `ajax`.

Here I am trying to load data from a simple table(name-details (name,age)) from mysql in `jsgrid`.

I have two 2 files 1)`index.php` 2)`hello.php` in the same folder

`index.php` :

```
<Doctype! HTML></Doctype!>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jsgrid.min.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="jsGrid"></div>

        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script  src="js/jsgrid.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`hello.php`

```
<?php

    switch($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) {

        case "GET":

            $dbhost = "localhost";  
            $dbuser = "root";
            $dbpsw = "";    
            $dbname= "tp";

            @$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpsw);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $data = array();
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM details"); 
            $stmt->execute();

            $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount(); //Rows count

            if ($affected_rows == 0) {

                echo "no data";
                exit();
            }

            foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {

                $data[] = $row;

            }
            echo json_encode($data);
            break;

    }

?>
```

`main.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        width: "70%",
        height: "400px",
        inserting: true,
        editing: true,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true,
        filtering:true,
        controller: {
            loadData: function(filter) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "hello.php",
                    data: filter
                });
            }
        },
        fields: [
            { name: "name", title: "Name", type: "text", width: 150 },
            { name: "age", title: "Age", type: "number", width: 50, filtering: false },
            { type: "control" }
        ]
    });
});
```

`hello.php` shows a perfect output of data from the database however in `index.php` no data is loaded into the `jsgrid` and it shows `not found`

Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a sample output of `hello.php`, starting from the very first character, which should be `[`.

Comment: [{"name":"sdff","age":10}]

Comment: In the `loadData` function, add after data:filter `, success: function(result) { console.log(result); }`.  Then in your (Chrome) browser, press F12 and click the Console tab.  Do you see `[Object]` which when expanded gives `Array[1]...`?

Comment: No i dont see anything like that .ON checking preserve log i just see navigated to : http://localhost:8080/jsgrid / which is the path to my index file .I tried using $.get and stringify the output in alert which is showing correct its just that jsgrid is not taking the json_encode

Comment: Can you try to make the call to the dbase outside the jsgrid and save it on a variable then call the variable as for example: jsondata = $.post('yourfile.php').done(function(data){ var dd = JSON.parse(data)},"json"); I will be trying it this week, il let you know the results